# Why doesn't `knitr`, when called from the console, use the same cache as when called from the IDE?

Tags: r, caching, knitr

When I knit a document in RStudio (by clicking on the "Knit") button, a cache folder gets created named after the file's name as `${filename}_cache`.

I would like to be able to inspect the objects created by the compilation, and have them in my workspace. To do that I call `knit()` from the console:

```
knit("filename.Rmd")
```

The workspace now contains all the objects, but doing so created a cache named simply `cache/`.

I've tried to trick knitr into using the same cache name with an option:

```
opts_chunk$set(cache.path = "filename_cache/")
```

Now it would appear that the same cache directory is used, but calling `knit()` from the command line seems to invalidate the cache created when clicking on the "Knit" button.

For example, if you have this document, saved as `cache.Rmd`:

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(cache.path = "cache_cache/")
```

```{r, cache=TRUE}
foo <- rnorm(10)
foo
```
````

You will have different results if you compile this with the "Knit" button or from the console.

Is there a way to use the same cache, independently on how `knit()` was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For R Markdown documents, do not call `knitr::knit()` but `rmarkdown::render()` instead. **rmarkdown** = **knitr** + Pandoc, and **rmarkdown** modifies several default chunk options in **knitr**, including the `cache.path` option ([see source](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/07f7d8ef8db1774a35b4bcf427d443218aeea9c8/R/render.R#L364)).